# completionhandler in for in loop

Tags: ios, swift, loops, asynchronous, completionhandler

I am running a completionhandler inside a for in loop, so yeah an async operation inside a loop...

Thats why I included `DispatchGroups()`:

```
for fileName in fileNames {
    group.enter()
    let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: "\(self.documentsUrl.path)/\(fileName)")
    let ref = storage.reference().child("pathTo/\(fileName)")
    let _ = ref.putFile(from: url, metadata: nil) { metadata, error in
         print("completed")
         if let error = error {
             print("error")
         } else {
             print("success")
         }
         self.removeFile()
         group.leave()
     }
  }
  group.notify(queue: .main, execute: {
      print("finished")
  })
```

Well, the filepath´s exists, but I dont get any prints in the console, but I need to get notified after each async operation is finished. Could anybody help me with this?

Comment: what happens if you put all your for code in DispatchQueue.main.async{} method instead of group.enter ?

Comment: Put breakpoint and see whats printing. btw "completed" is printing or not?

Comment: hey, i included DispatchQueue.main.async{} and there is still no printing in console..could anybody guide me how to get the callback working, so i can react on successfull/error events?

Comment: What is not printing in console ? Could you please explain , Where did you call your completion Handler ?

Comment: You want to notify after ALL operation finished ? Then just call your closure after the finished statement you printed

Comment: ehm i didnt call any completionhandler, thats why i am asking..where to put it

Comment: and i want to get notifed after each upload

Comment: What does `ref.putFile(from: metadata:)` return, a boolean? Put a breakpoint literally on `print("completed")`. If the breakpoint is never reached, that code isn't firing for sure.

Answer (score 0):

I am *ASSUMING* you're uploading to Firebase.

Couple of things to try:
Change `let _ = ref.putFile(from: url...` to `let uploadObj = ref.putFile(from: url...`
Then, as the last line of your for loop do this: `uploadObj.resume()`.

If that doesn't work, then my best guess is that Firebase's framework can't handle multiple simultaneous uploads. The solution to that is to wait for each file to finish uploading, then upload the next one.

You can also try your code, but only have it upload 1 file. If that works, then the problem is most likely the concurrent upload issue. Try it with 2, and then keep going if it doesn't fail. If it does eventually fail, then the simultaneity is definitely the issue.

If you insist on attempting simultaneous uploads, then go to [Google's documentation on this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/upload-files), and implement their examples to monitor uploads. Then you'll be able to see exactly what's going on with each upload.

Here's an update:
[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37770377/8462094)'s answer also suggests uploading one at a time.