# Swift 3 Google Firebase Multi Upload

Tags: swift, multithreading, firebase, firebase-storage

i am currently trying to upload multiple file from my device to google firebase, here is my setup:

```
func upload(completionHandler: @escaping (Bool) -> ()) { 
    let fileNames = try fileManager.contentsOfDirectory(atPath: documentsUrl.path)    
    for fileName in fileNames {
        let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: "\(FileService.shared.documentsUrl.path)/\(fileName)")
        let ref = storage.reference().child("path/\(fileName)")

        let upload = ref.putFile(from: url, metadata: nil, completion: { (metadata, error) in
            if error != nil {
                completionHandler(true)
            }

            completionHandler(true)
        })
    }
}
```

How i call it:

```
self.upload { (success) in
    print("operation \(success)")
}
```

What i see:

When i just have one file in the document directory, the loop runs just once and the file is being uploaded!

BUT: When there are multiple files, the loops also runs multiple times and the files are NOT being uploaded!

```
FIRStorageErrorDomain Code=-13000
```

Anybody could help me with this?

Thanks and Greetings!

Comment: You can find a solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45750569/8236481

Comment: i have the exact same business logic in my code.. can you refer to it?

Comment: or could one show me the PromiseKit implementation of this?