# Upload Multiple Images in a Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I am trying to upload multiple images using a for loop. I have got all my fileuri in a list and while completing tasks only the last image is getting uploaded several times.

If I am uploading five images then the last image is getting uploaded five times.

I have also tried adding all the tasks to a list and looping it. But still only the last image is getting uploaded.

```
foreach(imgurl){

final StorageReference storageReference = mStorageReference.child("/photos" + "/photo" + (count + 1));

UploadTask uploadTask = storageReference.putFile(imgUrl);

Task<Uri> urlTask = uploadTask.continueWithTask(new Continuation<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot, Task<Uri>>() {
                        @Override
                        public Task<Uri> then(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) throws Exception {
                            if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                                throw task.getException();
                            }
                            return storageReference.getDownloadUrl();
                        }
                    }).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Uri>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Uri> task) {
                            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                Uri downloadUri = task.getResult();
                                addPhoto(downloadUri.toString());

                            } else {
                                Log.d(TAG, "onFailure: Photo upload failed.");
                                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Photo upload failed ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }
                    });

}

}
```

Comment: A similar question was answered on this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37769701/uploading-multiple-images-simultaneously-with-google-firebase Cheers

Comment: If I have tried that too but only the last image is getting uploaded several times..@GbadegesinTaiwo

Answer (score 0):

if you have 5 images, those 5 images should contain a different imgUrl, you are iterating N times to the upload code to Firebase Storage with the same uploadTask

```
UploadTask uploadTask = storageReference.putFile(imgUrl); --> This same task

tasks.add(uploadTask);

for (UploadTask str : tasks) { --> is repeating N times with the same imgUrl

Task<Uri> urlTask = str.continueWithTask(new Continuation<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot, Task<Uri>>() {
                        @Override
                        public Task<Uri> then(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) throws Exception {
                            ...
```

What you should do is to move your forEach loop to handle each different imgUrl and then upload each on to your Storage, for example

Pseudocode

```
forEach(imgUrl) {
   uploadtask = storageReference.putFile(imgUrl);
   tasks.add(uploadTask);

   Task<Uri> urlTask = str.continueWithTask(new Continuation<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot, Task<Uri>>() {
                        @Override
                        public Task<Uri> then(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) throws Exception {
                            ...
```

Comment: I have tried that too but when it reaches Task<Uri> it iterates to the next imageurl and then at last iteration it uploads the last imageurl several times.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this, it works for me!

```
private void uploadImages() {
    findViewById(R.id.add).setEnabled(false);
    findViewById(R.id.add).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.border_buttons_disable);
    builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    builder.setTitle("Adding " + type);
    builder.setMessage("We are validating data...");
    alertDialog = builder.create();
    alertDialog.setCancelable(false);
    alertDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
    alertDialog.show();
    for (int i = 0; i < urls.size(); i++) {
        UploadTask uploadTask = (UploadTask) storageReference.child("images/businesses/products/" + preferencesAdapter.getId() + "-" + _sku + "-" + i + ".png").putFile(Uri.parse(urls.get(i))).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                taskSnapshot.getStorage().getDownloadUrl().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Uri>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Uri> task) {
                        selectedPictures.add(task.getResult().toString().substring(0, task.getResult().toString().indexOf("&token")));
                        if (selectedPictures.size() == urls.size()) {
                            alertDialog.dismiss();
                            addProduct();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Just create these array:
`ArrayList<String> urls;`

And for each image user select from intent add to "urls"